# UIPageViewController - transparent areas on view controllers blend wrong

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, uipageviewcontroller

Is there a way to tell UIPageViewController to not do shadowing or blending on pixels with alpha value of 0? Right now those areas show up translucent and it looks really bad.

Even better would be a way to specify my own shadow path.

[image: Example]